# Ignorar parâmetro caso esteja null

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Tenho o seguinte método que faz uma busca no banco de dados:

```
public Collection<Habilidade> pesquisar(HabilidadeForm form) throws Exception {
        String query = "select u from Habilidade u where u.nome like ?1 and u.geracao = ?2";
        Collection<Habilidade> resultado =
            em.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, "%" + form.getNome() + "%")
                .setParameter(2, form.getGeracao()).getResultList();

        return resultado.isEmpty() ? findAll() : resultado;
    }
```

Caso eu faça a mesma query no banco ficaria assim um exemplo:

```
select * from habilidade where nome like '%Bl%' and geracao_id = null;
```

Tenho um problema onde nenhuma geração é null, daí caio na pegadinha que ele não vai trazer nada caso geracao seja null. Como posso resolver fazer por exemplo: Se a geracao for null ignore ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Douglas, na forma que entendi o problema, é recomendável criar a lógica para verificar se o seu formulário a *geraçao_id* não é null, montar o select e se necessário passar o parâmetro. No caso abaixo se a *geracao_id* for *null*, o select apenas considerará o nome.

```
public Collection<Habilidade> pesquisar(HabilidadeForm form) throws Exception {
    String query = "select u from Habilidade u where u.nome like ?1";

    if (form.getGeracao() != null) {
       query +=  " and u.geracao = ?2";
    } 

    Query q = em.createQuery(query);
    q.setParameter(1, "%" + form.getNome() + "%");

    if (form.getGeracao() != null) {
        q.setParameter(2, form.getGeracao());
    }   

    Collection<Habilidade> resultado = q.getResultList();

    return resultado.isEmpty() ? findAll() : resultado;
}
```